# On omitting "to be"

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs, dialect

I've (though rarely) more than once run into phrases where a usual "to be" happened to be omitted. For example:

> That needed done as soon as possible

Whereas usually one (at least a non-native speaker) would have probably instead expected:

> That needed *to be* done as soon as possible

I'm curious as to whether:

1. This is a common form
2. This is acceptable in both informal and formal situations
3. This can be extended to other verbs. For example:

   > That had done as soon as possible

   makes my ears bleed a little bit, but given that "that needed done as soon as possible" is acceptable that might be just because I'm not used to the construction.

Comment: Regarding the comment from @Yay, where are you? Seems this may be a factor.

Comment: @user3169 Nowhere near where that'd be used: I can't really remember where exactly I learned about it the first time, but I'm sure I've seen it again be used in some chatroom here on SE. So it would be a regionalism?

Answer (score 1):

> That needed done as soon as possible.

is incorrect, but you could use:

> That needed **doing** as soon as possible.

The last example needs a *to be*.

> That had **to be** done as soon as possible.

Comment: Please check out [what Grammar Girl says on the matter](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/needs-washed)

Comment: OK, but it is a regional usage at best. For reference, I don't live near a blue dot.

Answer (score 0):

### Need is a transitive verb

A transitive verb means that the verb requires a direct object, a noun.  You can't just say

> I need

and call it a complete sentence.  What do I need?

### Done is not a noun

Done is an adjective, and it is a past participle of `to do`.

Consider this, you wouldn't say

> George needs blue
>
> Pattie needs lost
>
> Bobby needs found
>
> Sherry needs dirty

Those are all **incomplete** sentences.  Need requires an object as I pointed out.

These are all **complete** sentences:

> The bald guy needs hair
>
> Stephanie needs water
>
> Vanessa needs glucose

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/need_1